# View largest files on computer

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, file-management

I'm using windows 7 ultimate 64 bit, and have had success with Tree File size, but I'm looking for a way to scan the hard drive and list the largest files, not necessarily the folder sizes, but by individual files in whatever folder they might be in.

Is there a program out there like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd take a look at [SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/). It does a graphical display of the files for you. I like it because it's fast and free.

Comment: @Potter: Your recommendation is a trojan containing software :( Here is the report scanned from virustotal.com http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=345c849722ad29a6eb1d724b2b4eb83dff8281b5b4ac4b90710b6a7333a1e8a6-1298660890

Comment: 1. I've never heard of Virus Total. 2. I've scanned the file and installation folder with Microsoft Security Essentials and I can't see any Trojan. 3. You're the only one claiming this is an infection in the 8 years it has been available. 4. I looked at what the Trojan is supposed to infect, and I can't find any trace of it in my Windows folder or registry.

Comment: Also, the "infection" was flagged by Jiangmin AV, which I've never heard of. All the other major AV vendors showed nothing in your URL.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [**WinDirStat**](http://windirstat.info/) (scroll for download link).

Alternatively, get it from [Download.com](http://download.cnet.com/WinDirStat/3000-2248_4-10614592.html), if you're more comfortable.

Comment: ...or, as *Randolph Potter* mentioned, check out **SequoiaView**.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to SequoiaView, I would suggest checking out [JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/features.html). 
It does the same thing, but in pie-chart format. It is freeware. And, since it's a java app, it can run on any OS that has a JVM.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Never heard of JDiskReport. I'm going to give it a spin!

Comment: I've used it but I found I liked WinDirStat better. It's sort of a personal preference, though - both are perfectly functional programs (and not bad-looking either).